# Usage of the SecurityType as None while connecting to a database?

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I am connecting to a database and have one line which is

```
<rd:SecurityType>None</rd:SecurityType>
```

My database does not have any security type i.e. I removed this line and I am still able to connect to the database successfully, can I remove this line? Can there be any implications in any case that a connection may be refused by the database cause of removing this line?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can remove it and everything works, then the answer is "yes".

The only thing to bear in mind is if a future version of reporting services changes the default value of that property or decides that the property is required, then it could have unintended consequences.

At the end of the day, if it's not impacting anything being there then I'd leave it alone.